# Push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected with Rails and Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm getting "Push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected" when I try to push to Heroku with a Rails app. I actually just pushed a  rails app to Heroku yesterday, so I don't know why it's not working.

**Output from "git push heroku master":**

```
Colin@LAPTOP ~/floobits/share/aeip/tenk_hours/tenk_hours (master)
$git push heroku master
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/Colin/.ssh/id_rsa':
Initializing repository, done.
Counting objects: 87, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (80/80), done.
Writing objects: 100% (87/87), 18.05 KiB, done.
Total 87 (delta 18), reused 0 (delta 0)

!Push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected

To git@heroku.com:nameless-journey-5485.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:nameless-journey-5485.git'
```

**Output from ls -R:**

```
$ ls -R
.:
Gemfile       app  config     db   npm-debug.log  rakefile     test
Gemfile.lock  bin  config.ru  log  public         readme.rdoc  tmp

./app:
assets  controllers  helpers  models  views

./app/assets:
javascripts  stylesheets

./app/assets/javascripts:
application.js  pages.js.coffee

./app/assets/stylesheets:
application.css  pages.css.scss

./app/controllers:
application_controller.rb  pages_controller.rb

./app/helpers:
application_helper.rb  pages_helper.rb

./app/models:
user.rb

./app/views:
devise  layouts  pages

./app/views/devise:
confirmations  mailer  passwords  registrations  sessions  shared  unlocks

./app/views/devise/confirmations:
new.html.erb

./app/views/devise/mailer:
confirmation_instructions.html.erb    unlock_instructions.html.erb
reset_password_instructions.html.erb

./app/views/devise/passwords:
edit.html.erb  new.html.erb

./app/views/devise/registrations:
edit.html.erb  new.html.erb

./app/views/devise/sessions:
new.html.erb

./app/views/devise/shared:
_links.erb

./app/views/devise/unlocks:
new.html.erb

./app/views/layouts:
_header.html.erb  application.html.erb

./app/views/pages:
about.html.erb  home.html.erb

./bin:
bundle  rails  rake  spring

./config:
application.rb  database.yml    environments  locales    secrets.yml
boot.rb         environment.rb  initializers  routes.rb

./config/environments:
development.rb  production.rb  test.rb

./config/initializers:
backtrace_silencers.rb  filter_parameter_logging.rb  session_store.rb
cookies_serializer.rb   inflections.rb               wrap_parameters.rb
devise.rb               mime_types.rb

./config/locales:
devise.en.yml  en.yml

./db:
development.sqlite3  migrate  schema.rb  seeds.rb

./db/migrate:
20140309003157_devise_create_users  20140309011749_add_devise_to_users
20140309011702_add_devise_to_users  20140309012636_add_devise_to_users.rb

./log:
development.log

./public:
404.html  422.html  500.html  favicon.ico  robots.txt

./test:
controllers  fixtures  helpers  models  test_helper.rb

./test/controllers:
pages_controller_test.rb

./test/fixtures:
users.yml

./test/helpers:
pages_helper_test.rb

./test/models:
user_test.rb

./tmp:
cache  pids  sessions  sockets

./tmp/cache:
assets

./tmp/cache/assets:
development

./tmp/cache/assets/development:
sprockets

./tmp/cache/assets/development/sprockets:
016a7d7cc5eb9d06106779543621d9c8  8f2511830f6e103d24928dac99a5cf5a
03b698a2c9aa93bd7c52f705fc22f1df  ab8bf3231a4801920fc5d2aec4b331ca
08d3afa2bedbb7c09930e205f6961227  ad66576bc2dafacbeeee8e0409752bc3
0f971999de889bbcd9966dfbd1642dba  ae4feeec513d58386d2e3dac32f99ee8
10d63772dd907e9f2558ef9f84ad61a8  ae58df63a5c84bde6bddebf2ea3e1735
13fe41fee1fe35b49d145bcc06610705  afb4267d08cb6b156a2750978afed6b9
1ba2331aab000dc355521d376087bf32  b3164c7f18ab16bf662ce0ec2480bb2a
2786e5bdea97d6a26b9a32bbb490e668  b339542398b5c9debb920dcd92daeaa7
2f5173deea6c795b8fdde723bb4b63af  b7cf1ee5c56fa85d2cf039f2541df071
357970feca3ac29060c1e3861e2c0953  c6a2024881e909ba3cf9dfe6c7f5d8b3
49664a76aba52e14c929ecafc4824c2b  cffd775d018f68ce5dba1ee0d951a994
4f6f9048d51c588d406ad1c72f794059  d0b1fa49c70d1017b5464c7fcc7c7346
581701290421a0ceefc5b3c0654c83a4  d3f1a0542c3383efc26d8046c720c591
58d13fa8238ddbe40924e2b2b8e2b892  d771ace226fc8215a3572e0aa35bb0d6
59b6df7cd19590bc9a657cc2d25c33aa  e4ad82fa2b67858d47fe0e8cd0e0d3bf
7b4ffef8396bcf7a78bbbea365739cf1  f5f738b65b700d4d150982435be7b758
827c4bfa9291d165682c7716ed7bac70  f7cbd26ba1d28d48de824f0e94586655
8d467b2390a5eab42a9d2d3d89792e32

./tmp/pids:
server.pid

./tmp/sessions:

./tmp/sockets:
```

Comment: Post the complete log & also do a `ls -R` in your rails app & paste the output here

Answer (score 0):

Heroku doesn't know what type of application you are pushing (Cedar vs Bamboo). You will need to create a file called `Procfile` in the top-level of your Rails app to tell Heroku it is a Cedar app.

More information is here:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile

This simple `Procfile` should get you started:

```
web: bundle exec rails server
```

You probably don't want to run Webrick in production for too long, but for development purposes it should be fine. Eventually you'll probably want to [use the Unicorn server](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-unicorn).